# porting Java 8 code to Java 7

Tags: spring, java-7, java-8

Is it possible to port this fragment of code from Java 8 to Java 7?

```
    protected UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return (username) -> {
            User u = crmService.findUserByUsername(username);
            return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
                    u.getUsername(), u.getPassword(), u.isEnabled(),
                    u.isEnabled(), u.isEnabled(), u.isEnabled(),
                    AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("USER", "write"));
        };
    }
```

Comment: You should read about lambda expression in java 8.

Comment: Most IDEs will let you refactor between lambda expressions and inner classes.  So by editing this in an 8-aware IDE, you can refactor back to an inner class expression and then compile under Java 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in such way:

```
protected UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    return new UserDetailsService() {
        @Override
        UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
                User u = crmService.findUserByUsername(username);
                return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
                        u.getUsername(), u.getPassword(), u.isEnabled(),
                        u.isEnabled(), u.isEnabled(), u.isEnabled(),
                        AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("USER", "write"));
        }
    }

}
```

But definitely you should think about extracting it to normal class and just returning new object there

Comment: Great! Thank you so much Jakub, i was stuck with this problem (found good example of Outh2+Rest but only for Java 8)